# Saving Information For The Duration The User Has A Site open

Tags: asp.net

How woulld I set this up:

I wanna save what links a user clicks on in a website. I thought of creating a jquery function that would save the link name everytime a link is clicked , then ajax the info to the db after the user closes the site.

Does that sound like a proper way. Anyone have samples of that?

Since there are multiple pages with multpile links, I wanna create something equivalient to a Session variable in javascript so I can append info to it everytime a user clicks a link and send the info only once to the db, instead of everytime a user clicks a link open a db connection and send the info.

The links are products so I wanna save related products, so I wanna save related product infomation. Maybe I need a cookie instead?

Comment: Have you considered [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waiting till the user leaves the site is nice in theory but never in practice.  Because you can't really know for sure when a user is leaving -- or it might be to late (eg a user shuts down the computer.)  What you really want to do is keep track of the actions of the user as they happen using ajax.

To do this you need to assign every user session a unique id.  ASP.NET does this for you (there is a session cookie created for every visitor to the site.)  Using the ASP.NET session identifier will save you a lot of work.

Every time a user performs an action you want to save you just have jQuery make an ajax call (you don't care about the return) to a service that logs to your DB.

Here is the Microsoft docs about the automatic SessionID [MS Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid.aspx%20MSDOC)

Or simply use the following code to get the unique id:

```
string sessID =  System.Web.SessionState.SessionID;
```

Comment: Can i mix asp code with jQuery code? How do i access the session id via jquery?

Comment: @Nick - You don't.  The jQuery (on the client) posts to a service and does not worry about it.  The service code (on the server) uses the line above to find out the SessionID of the client's session that called the service.  The details of handling the request and response objects are auto-magically handled by the .net platform.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler way is just give user unique cookie. On server you always know on what page user come in. (`$_SERVER` in `php`) so your server side script could save it in database (with `SID`).

Comment: If reported, the `REFERER` could also be stored with the clicked link.

Answer (score 0):

use localStorage for HTML5 browsers or cookies for older browsers.

```
$("a").click(function() {
    car links = localStorage["links"];
    links = JSON.parse(links);
    links.push(this.href);
    localStorage["links"] = JSON.stringify(links);
});
```

Then listen to the onbeforeunload event and make an ajax call to the browser sending it the localStorage["links"] JSON.

Comment: Modify document.cookie to set it as a cookie. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie for an example.